# Slow mysqldump export in Amazon RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I need to migrate a MySQL database in Amazon RDS to another local environment, but the dump is extremely slow. The internet connection is fine; could there be some restrictions in AWS?

For example, in a MySQL 5.7 instance with the db.t2.micro instance class, dumping a database of 200 MB took 8 minutes.

And there are other MySQL instances to dump, some of which are 200 GB.

How can I improve it in AWS?

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions to improve AWS export speed.

Comment: Try getting a spot instance into the same VPC and doing the dump to there, pushing that to S3, and downloading from S3. Also check your RDS instance stats in CloudWatch - CPU, disk burst, that sort of thing.